# How to fetch calendar data from an API to flutter calendar

Tags: flutter, dart

May anyone please help me how I can fetch calendar data from a URL
"https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/ejservices/api/Schedule/LoadData" to my flutter calendar app.
I have a model event.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Event {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final DateTime from;
  final DateTime to;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final bool isAllDay;

  Event({
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.from,
    required this.to,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.lightGreen,
    this.isAllDay = false,
  });
}
```

Here is the event_data_source.dart

```
import 'package:calendar_app/model/event.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

class EventDataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  EventDataSource(List<Event> appointments) {
    this.appointments = appointments;
  }

  Event getEvent(int index) => appointments![index] as Event;

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) => getEvent(index).from;

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) => getEvent(index).to;

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) => getEvent(index).title;

  // @override
  // String getDescription(int index) => getEvent(index).description;

  @override
  Color getColor(int index) => getEvent(index).backgroundColor;

  @override
  bool isAllDay(int index) => getEvent(index).isAllDay;
}
```

Here is event_provider.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:calendar_app/model/event.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class EventProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Event> _events = [];

  List<Event> get events => _events;

  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  DateTime get selectedDate => _selectedDate;

  get http => null;

  void setDate(DateTime date) => _selectedDate = date;

  List<Event> get eventsOfSelectedDate => _events;

  void addEvent(Event event) {
    _events.add(event);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteEvent(Event event) {
    _events.remove(event);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void editEvent(Event newEvent, Event oldEvent) {
    final index = _events.indexOf(oldEvent);
    _events[index] = newEvent;

    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

I request assistance on how I can use data from the above URL and fit in my model to be able to display in my calendar app.